# Callback/Promise nested loop, 2 API calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

My apologies about the title I couldn't find anything better.
if this problem has an answer already feel free to inform me in the comments below and ill delete it right away but keep it in mind this is not a general question.

**Explanation**:
There is an API call that will fetch data from the server (an array) and then based on that array it will start a loop, inside the loop we have another API based on parent index (child make API call by using parent index) and get some data and map them into a variable (an array). I need to call a callback after the last child of the last parent done his job.

---

**Mimic code**:

```
for(let i=0;i<2;++i){
    for(let j=0;j<2;++j){
        map data into another array with predefined shape
        console.log(i +", "+ j)
    }
}
console.log('good to go for callback');
```

#### Desirable result

```
0, 0
0, 1
1, 0
1, 1
good to go for callback
```

---

**Real code:**

```
var projects = api.getProjects(req);

projects.then(function(response){
    response.projects.map(_e => {
        var project = api.getProjectContent(_e.id);
        project.then(function(_response){
            _response.content.map(e=> {
                a_globa_array.push(...);
                console.log('hello');
            });
        });
    });

    console.log('yellow');
});
```

I want to exactly after every single child from every single parent pushed into an array, print *"yellow"* in the console (or get the length of the array).

---

**What I've tried so far:**

```
var projects = api.getProjects(req);

projects.then(function(response){
    Promise.all(response.projects.map(_e => {
        var project = api.getProjectContent(_e.id);
        project.then(function(_response){
            _response.content.map(e=> {
                a_globa_array.push(...);
                console.log('hello');
            });
        });
    })).then(()=>{ console.log('yellow'); });
});
```

And

```
var projects = api.getProjects(req);

projects.then(function(response){
    let pr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {response.projects.map(_e => {
        var project = api.getProjectContent(_e.id);
        project.then(function(_response){
            _response.content.map(e=> {
                a_globa_array.push(...);
                console.log('hello');
            });
        });
    })) });

    pr.then(()=>{ console.log('yellow'); });
});
```

And some more. Typo in above codes are not important because i wrote them in SO editor so maybe I missed some parentheses/curly braces. Additional info: **There is no errors**. If you think there is better solutions rather than promise (async/await ...) please let me know and share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it with the first `Promise.all` snippet, but the function inside it doesn't return the promise it created, so you're calling `Promise.all` on an array of undefined.

Try this (same thing, with added `return`):

```
var projects = api.getProjects(req);

projects.then(function(response){
    Promise.all(response.projects.map(_e => {
        var project = api.getProjectContent(_e.id);
        return project.then(function(_response){
            _response.content.map(e=> {
                a_globa_array.push(...);
                console.log('hello');
            });
        });
    })).then(()=>{ console.log('yellow'); });
});
```

Also, I would suggest avoiding `Array.map` when you're not actually returning any values. Using `forEach` instead makes the intent clearer (map is used for creating a new array, while forEach is simply a loop).

Comment: Thanks for the input, let me check

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt wasn't so far off. You just need not forget to `return` the promises from your callbacks, so that e.g. `then` or `Promise.all` can await them:

```
projects.then(function(response){
    return Promise.all(response.projects.map(_e => {
//  ^^^^^^
        var project = api.getProjectContent(_e.id);
        return project.then(function(_response) {
//      ^^^^^^
            return _response.content.map(e=> {
//          ^^^^^^
                console.log('hello');
                return ...;
//              ^^^^^^
            });
        });
    }));
}).then(array_of_arrays => {
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ you get the results here
    // you can un-nest this then() call
    console.log('yellow');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for edit and the input. I didn't check your solution yet but @riv solution worked for me so i checked that as an answer. +1 for your time and your solution

Comment: That's a bit overkill on the return statements, as only one of them is used.

Comment: @riv A function that doesn't return a value is useless. And at least the outer three `return` statements *are* necessary for this code to work (I don't know what the `content.map(…)` loop does)

Comment: Since when are return-less functions useless? Outer return is only needed if the code is reordered to put the output outside the first then (which is good, but wasn't part of the question), and third return is only needed if you want to access the results of promise.all, which is not the case here as we only need to know when it completes.

Comment: @riv If it doesn't return anything, its a [procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedure_(computer_science)) not a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) :-D And yes, I try to write good code in general, not just something that "works" for some specific question scenario.